# Why do I have to initialize pointers as variables?

Tags: c++

This piece of code below works fine.
// example on constructors and destructors

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int *width, *height;
  public:
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {return (*width * *height);}
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = new int;
  height = new int;
  *width = a;
  *height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
  delete width;
  delete height;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect (3,4), rectb (5,6);
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But why couldn't I use another piece of code below instead? It didn't compile by using the code below but if I force to run it will still generate correct result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
  //here I didn't initialize these two variables' pointers.
  int width, height;
public:
  CRectangle (int a,int b);
  ~CRectangle ();
  int area () {
    return (width * height);
  }
};

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = a;
  height = b;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {

}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect (3,4), rectb (5,6);
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't force code that hasn't been compiled to run. Are you sure you didn't run the last successful build?

Comment: `width` and `height` aren't pointers, so you should just multiply them directly, not dereference them. And you can't delete them because you never allocated them.

Comment: And what @Barmar says is the most correct way to do it, not the first.

Comment: And why on earth are you allocating the simple integers width and height on the heap?  Are there rectangles without width or height?

Comment: Oh, another C++ question from another guy who comes from Java...

Answer (score 3):

In your second piece of code

```
int area () {
   return (*width * *height);
}

.
.
.

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
  delete width;
  delete height;
}
```

in `return (*width * *height);`, you're dereferencing `width` and `height` which are not pointers. Also, in your destructor, you're `delete`ing `width` and `height` which are not pointers initialized with `new` and are therefore invalid operations. What's correct is

```
int area () {
   return (width * height);  // Do not dereference width and height
}

.
.
.

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
  // Do something else without the deletes or remove the destructor altogether
}
```

Also, as what @chris has pointed out in his comment, you can also remove the destructor (be sure to remove both the declaration and the definition).

Comment: True, but the destructor is likely perfectly fine to be left out altogether.

Comment: @chris Yes. But I think that would cause a tiny bit of confusion in the OP's part. :)

Comment: Better to clear it up now then :) I barely ever need destructors.

Comment: I edited my post. So is it possible to release memory by using destructor for second one?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a structure which contains two pointers to integers that have to be located somewhere else in memory. So when `CRectangle` is created, there are three new objects: the `CRectangle` itself, and then two integers elsewhere.

In Object Oriented Programming terms, `CRectange` is associated with two `int` objects via *aggregation*.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int *width, *height;
  public:
    CRectangle (int,int);
    ~CRectangle ();
    int area () {return (*width * *height);}
};
```

Now here, the situation is different: two `int` objects are embedded inside a `CRectangle`.  When you create a `CRectangle` object, those integers exist inside it already. They have an address in memory and so you can make pointers to them, but
they are accessed relative to the address of `CRectangle`.  Inside the member functions of `CRectangle`, when you access `width` it really means `this->width`. The pointer to the object is involved, but invisibly. If we have the pointer to the object, then its fields can be found just by a displacement relative to the pointer. Since C++ isn't assembly language, the compiler works out this displacement calculation for you and generates the machine code.

The association between `CRectangle` and the two integers is now *composition*.

```
class CRectangle {
  //here I didn't initialize these two variables' pointers.
  int width, height;
public:
  CRectangle (int a,int b);
  ~CRectangle ();
  int area () {
    return (*width * *height);
  }
};
```

In the `area` function, you should not be using the unary operator `*` for pointer dereferencing, because `width` and `height` are not pointers. It does not apply.
(Please ensure that your examples compile cleanly before posting them, except for examples that specifically illustrate some troublesome non-compilation.)